# TypeError: Error #1009 with loading external SWF file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was making 3D File Viewer in Flash Player with AS3.0
and i found AWD Viewer from Away3D Example File.
(http://awaytools.com/awaybuilder/tutorial-01/AwayBuilderTutorial01_SampleFiles.zip)

it works fine.

and i loaded it in my 'Main' swf file. but it's not work. it kept showing error to me.

error message is below

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at AWDViewer/initEngine()[C:\Users\wintec\Desktop\Flash3DViewer\source\AWDViewer.as:74]
    at AWDViewer/init()[C:\Users\wintec\Desktop\Flash3DViewer\source\AWDViewer.as:57]
    at AWDViewer()[C:\Users\wintec\Desktop\Flash3DViewer\source\AWDViewer.as:49]
```

and that error line is just this

```
line 74 : stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
line 57 : initEngine();
line 49 : init();
```

and I know that error message mean there's no properties that name.
I checked that, there's nothing wrong.
also, when I loading another swf file in my 'Main'swf,  that's works. weird...

I don't understand why this error kept showing.
please help me.

### below code is from Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Flash3DViewer extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("AWDViewer.swf"); 
        private var _loader:Loader = new Loader() 

        public function Flash3DViewer()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            stop();
            _loader.load(_request);
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, initLoaded);
        }
        private function initLoaded():void
        {
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, initLoaded);
            var extSwf = _loader.content as MovieClip;
            swfContainer.addChild(extSwf);
            trace("contents loaded");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this error before, typically it occurs when an object attempts to reference the `stage` object _before_ it has been added to the stage.

Comment: did you mean I have to change calling method sequence?
if it is, `ADDED_TO_STAGE` can be solve this problem?

Comment: I can show you what you need to try, but first you'll have to show me the code that you are using to add the Flash3DViewer object to the stage.

Comment: this is my whole Flash3DViewer code.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz2c268ubzfg37k/Flash3DViewer.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with your application based on the code you provided via DropBox.  And just as I suspected, the `stage` property was being referenced before the object's addition to the stage was completed, which is why the null reference error was being generated.

The `AWDViewer` class was prematurely calling the `stage` property from one of the functions that is being called when the `init` function is called. I've updated the `Flash3DViewer.as` and `AWDViewer.as` files with the proper usage of the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event so that this does not occur.  I have also added comments to the code for you to follow along. Also, I had to modify the `init` function in the `AWDViewer` class to take a parameter of type `Event` to account for the fact that the function is now called when the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event fires.

**Flash3DViewer.as:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Flash3DViewer extends MovieClip
    {
        private var loader:Loader;

        public function Flash3DViewer():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            loadSWF("AWDViewer.swf");
        }
        private function loadSWF(url:String):void
        {
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded, false, 0, true);
            loader.load(urlRequest);
            addChild(loader);
        }
        private function onLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var target:AWDViewer = e.currentTarget.loader.content as AWDViewer;
            trace(target);
            //target.init();   // no longer need to call the init function manually as the AWDViewer calls it when it 'knows' it has been added to the stage.  This line can be deleted.
            addChild(target);
        }
    }
}
```

**AWDViewer.as:**

```
    public function AWDViewer()
    {
        /* Used ADDED_TO_STAGE event to know when to trigger the init 
           function call to avoid the null reference errors when accessing 
           the 'stage' property */
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        // init();  // no longer need to manually call the init function as the ADDED_TO_STAGE event listener will take care of this.  This line can be deleted.
    }

    /**
     * Global initialise function
     */
    public function init(e:Event):void
    {
        initEngine();
        initListeners();

        AssetLibrary.enableParser(AWD2Parser);

        //kickoff asset loading
        var loader:Loader3D = new Loader3D();
        loader.load(new URLRequest("assets/monkey.awd"));

        _view.scene.addChild(loader);
    }
```

While I did attempt to compile the code above, and the null reference errors ceased to generate with my corrected code, there were some compiler errors on my machine because of the different configurations of our computers.  You'll just need to ensure that these compiler errors do not appear on your machine.

```
Warning: Library path "C:\Users\wintec\Desktop\3D_VR\source\libs" does not resolve to a valid directory.
Warning: Library path "$(FlexSDK)/frameworks/libs/flex.swc" does not resolve to a valid file.
```

If you have any other questions, just let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! it was very helpful. the error is gone!
but... unfortunately it's not showing 3d object. :-(

I've imported away3d classes in 'Flash3DViewer' too. but it's not work. and I can't find any mistake...

could you please help me one more time?

Comment: Sure, but since that is a separate issue, you should create a new post with details about that issue and I can try to help.

Comment: I wrote new post. would you please check
[**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616058/object-doesnt-appear-in-loaded-swf) ?

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you are trying to access something which has not been instantiated. You should put some breakpoints and run your app in debug mode when you are not sure what exactly is null.

It's very likely that stage is null in your case. Stage property of DisplayObject is set to the instance of app's stage when this display object is added to stage. However, all parents of this display object should be added to the stage too. Thus, make sure that the instance of Flash3DViewer has the stage before loading AWDViewer.